# Using PHP to parse URL and provide it as variable to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

Since I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere, so here comes the question. But before that, Thanks to anyone who answers/helps in anyway.

The pseudo-code of the index.php page is:

```
    <html>
            <head><script>
        <?php
        $links = parse_ini_file('links.ini');
        if(isset($_GET['l']) && array_key_exists($_GET['l'], $links)){
        $my_phpvar = $links[$_GET['l']];
        }
        else{
        header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
        echo 'Unknown link.';
        }
        ?>
        var myjsvar= <?php echo $my_phpvar; ?>
        function go(){
        document.cookie = "visited=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        window.location.href = "myjsvar";
            }
</script></head>
    <body><a id="myA1" href="javascript:go();" target="_blank">Click</a></body>
            </html>
```

As is evident, in the above code the **myjsvar** comes from **my_phpvar**, and **my_phpvar** comes from a seperate file **links.ini** (sorry if I'm boring you, since it's all evident in the code, but I don't wanna miss anything out for anyone who can help)

I have added some rules to the .htaccess file in the root of this directory where **index.php** is located. The rules that have been added are

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L]
```

The **links.ini** file looks like this:

```
ex = https://www.example.com
```

So the **Main Issue** is: When I browse the URL **http://www.yoursite.com/short/index.php?l=ex** , and Click the Button to initiate the **function go()**, it doesn't take me to the website **https://www.example.com**

Once again, Thanks to anyone who solves/helps to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose `jsvar` inside quotes:

```
var myjsvar = "<?php echo $my_phpvar; ?>";
```

and later, use it as a variable (and not sring):

```
window.location.href = myjsvar;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Didn't look at the basics and my mind was going haywire. Thank you so much once again.